# Writing unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I need to help. I need to write some unit test on this source code. I tried to write it, but I was unsuccesful.

```
public class PagedCollection<T> : ReadOnlyCollection<T>, 
IPagedCollection<T>

    {
        public int CurrentPage { get; }
        public int TotalPages { get; }
        public int PageSize { get; }
        public int TotalCount { get; }
        public bool HasPrevious => CurrentPage > 1;
        public bool HasNext => CurrentPage < TotalPages;

        public PagedCollection(ICollection<T> items, int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize) : base(items.ToList())
        {
            EnsureArg.IsGte(count, 0, nameof(count));
            EnsureArg.IsGt(pageNumber, 0, nameof(pageNumber));
            EnsureArg.IsGt(pageSize, 0, nameof(pageSize));

            TotalCount = count;
            CurrentPage = pageNumber;
            PageSize = pageSize;
            TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone to help me?

Comment: I assume this is C#. Please [edit] your question to fix the tag if that's not the case, and always remember to add a language tag in the future. Also please describe what you mean by "unsuccessful" and show what you tried so that people can help you fix it.

Comment: Are you trying to unit test the constructor? Constructors should not have business logic. based on the constructor I came to a couple of tests, those EnsureArg functions and the TotalPageg calculation. But you provided no description of what you wish to test.

Comment: _I tried to write it, but I was unsuccesful._ - Can you show what did you wrote? Did you had some specific problem? Sorry, but without more specific details your question clearly stays: "Please do my task for me" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Step 0 is to decide what sort of things your object should be doing. Each of these things become your test case. There are a couple of obvious candidates:

```
[Test]
public void RejectIfCountIsZero()
{
    ICollection<string> collection = new[] { "Hello", "World" };
    ArgumentOutOfRangeException e = Assert.Throws<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>(() => { new PagedCollection<string>(collection, 0, 1, 1); });
    Assert.That(e.ParamName, Is.EqualTo("count"));
}
```

etc for your other validations

You can test your total page logic

```
[Test]
public void RoundsUpTotalPagesIfNotDivisible()
{
    ICollection<string> collection = new[] { "Hello", "World" };
    PagedCollection<string> pagedCollection = new PagedCollection<string>(collection, 100, 3, 9);
    Assert.That(pagedCollection.TotalPages, Is.EqualTo(12));
}
```

Then do one for the case where the count is divisible.
Add one for your HasPrevious and HasNext properties with both expectations of true and false.
And of course the properties that are supposed to be initialised by your constructor get initialised.

Just test the things you require to not break in the future (and remove any code you don't need). Follow the pattern "Arrange", "Act", "Assert". Make each test independent of other tests. Some people say one assertion per test, but I am a bit more relaxed on that. Definitely try to avoid test cases that go through sets of processes. If you find yourself needing to call 15 methods in your "Arrange" before you can do your "Act", your design is too tightly coupled.

Good luck.